# How to access redux wrapper inside getInitialProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the store

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension"; 
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers"; 
const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk]; 
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

Inside `pages/_app.js` I use the wrapper

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}> 
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}
const makeStore = () => store;
const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

In `pages/index.js` Redux works

```
export default function Index() { 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { posts } = useSelector((state) => state.posts); 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPosts());
  }, []);
```

But in `pages/[cid].js` I can't do the above, I have to go through `getInitialProps` and that doesn't work

```
export default function Course(props) { }

Course.getInitialProps = async ({ store, query }) => { 
    // store doesn't exist
    const { cid } = query
    // const dispatch = useDispatch(); // doesn't work 
    return { cid }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorate:

```
const posts= JSON.parse(
  localStorage.getItem('posts')
);
```